# Output Field value in field.tpl

Tags: entities

I have a content type "Produkte" with the field "field_produktmerkmale" which is a term reference field addressing the taxonomy vocabulary "Produktmerkmale". The terms have a title, a description and an image field.

When I display "field_produktmerkmale" it shows only the title with a link to the taxonomy, but I want to display the images instead of the title. So I created the "field--field_produktmerkmale--produkte.tpl.php" to modify the output.

**But how do I know address the image from this template?** 

var_dump($items) gives me the following result: **(Just an excerpt of the first element)**

```
[1]=> array(4) {
    ["#type"]=> string(4) "link"
    ["#title"]=> string(15) "Batteriebetrieb"
    ["#href"]=> string(16) "taxonomy/term/89"
    ["#options"]=> array(3) {
        ["entity_type"]=> string(13) "taxonomy_term"
        ["entity"]=> object(stdClass)#154 (11) {
            ["tid"]=> string(2) "89"
            ["vid"]=> string(1) "9"
            ["name"]=> string(15) "Batteriebetrieb"
            ["description"]=> string(68) "Batteriebetrieb: Mit automatischer Abschaltung zur Batterieschonung"
            ["format"]=> string(8) "php_code"
            ["weight"]=> string(1) "0"
            ["language"]=> string(3) "und"
            ["i18n_tsid"]=> string(1) "0"
            ["vocabulary_machine_name"]=> string(15) "produktmerkmale"
            ["field_icon2"]=> array(1) {
                ["und"]=> array(1) {
                    [0]=> array(15) {
                        ["fid"]=> string(3) "805"
                        ["uid"]=> string(1) "1"
                        ["filename"]=> string(6) "CE.gif"
                        ["uri"]=> string(21) "public://icons/CE.gif"
                        ["filemime"]=> string(9) "image/gif"
                        ["filesize"]=> string(3) "525"
                        ["status"]=> string(1) "1"
                        ["timestamp"]=> string(10) "1394787947"
                        ["type"]=> string(5) "image"
                        ["rdf_mapping"]=> array(0) {
                        }
                        ["image_dimensions"]=> array(2) {
                            ["width"]=> string(2) "50"
                            ["height"]=> string(2) "50"
                        }
                        ["alt"]=> string(0) ""
                        ["title"]=> string(0) ""
                        ["width"]=> string(2) "50"
                        ["height"]=> string(2) "50"
                    }
                }
            }
            ["rdf_mapping"]=> array(5) {
                ["rdftype"]=> array(1) {
                    [0]=> string(12) "skos:Concept"
                }
                ["name"]=> array(1) {
                    ["predicates"]=> array(2) {
                        [0]=> string(10) "rdfs:label"
                        [1]=> string(14) "skos:prefLabel"
                    }
                }
                ["description"]=> array(1) {
                    ["predicates"]=> array(1) {
                        [0]=> string(15) "skos:definition"
                    }
                }
                ["vid"]=> array(2) {
                    ["predicates"]=> array(1) {
                        [0]=> string(13) "skos:inScheme"
                    }
                    ["type"]=> string(3) "rel"
                }
                ["parent"]=> array(2) {
                    ["predicates"]=> array(1) {
                        [0]=> string(12) "skos:broader"
                    }
                    ["type"]=> string(3) "rel"
                }
            }
        }
        ["attributes"]=> array(2) {
            ["typeof"]=> array(1) {
                [0]=> string(12) "skos:Concept"
            }
            ["property"]=> array(2) {
                [0]=> string(10) "rdfs:label"
                [1]=> string(14) "skos:prefLabel"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The data I need would be in field_icon2 with the filename and in description** (as a tooltip). But how do I address ut correctly?

I tried:

```
<?php print $item['#options']['entity']['description']; ?>
```

But I get and error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include()
```

Comment: See: [Rendering Drupal 7 Fields the Right Way](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way).

Comment: I tried using it, but it gives me an error: Notice: Undefined variable: nid in include()

Answer (score 0):

`$item['#options']['entity']` is an object, so you should be accessing "description" this way:

`$item['#options']['entity']->description`

But as Adam stated, you should render it the right way with `field_view_field` method. The error you mentioned it's just a problem with sending the right parameters to the method.

Comment: So should I render it in the node--produkte.tpl.php or in the field--field_produktmerkmale--produkte.tpl.php? But why is it the wrong parameter? Which parameter should I use? the tutorial said to send the $nid as a parameter, but since I am in a field.tpl I guess there is no access to the $nid?! Sorry, but I am new to drupal.